# Scroll down/up in specific pixel steps via mouse scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mousewheel, scrolltop

I'd like the window to scroll up or down in defined intervals/steps any time mouse scrolling is detected.

I already found a solution here that detects scrolling in either direction, but i just couldn't make it perform an animated scroll properly.

```
$(function(){
var lastScrollTop = 0, delta = 5;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();

   if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
      return;

if (st > lastScrollTop){

// downscroll code
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 100}, 1000);
       console.log('scroll down');
   } 


else {
// upscroll code    
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: -100}, 1000)
      console.log('scroll up');
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
});
```

Comment: You'll need to stop the default behavior of the scroll (`return false` or `event.preventDefault()`). Also if you want to increment then use `-=100` and `+=100` rather than using absolute values.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. Where would i insert that line? or could you make a quick fiddle please?

Comment: Also, if you use the jQuery mouse-scroll plugin you will receive which way the scroll was so you can scroll the correct direction. Those three pieces of information are all you need... good luck :)